# In xamarin forms,for android using mvvm concept to display action sheet?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, popup, actionsheetpicker

In xamarin forms, for android passed  itemsource as bindable property  of action sheet to rg plugin popup for displaying the values as popup .In itemsource,I got the values but it not displaying in popup.can anyone please help me to find out the issue.I have attached the sample code with  this.[Actionsheet sample link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12bgz-Epn4sHECgMtfza6dirKPGoNRFAK)

Comment: Please share relevant code instead for screenshot.

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of code and XAML.

Comment: Please delete S in try part of ActionSheetPopup.xmal.cs inside the method OnItemSourceChanged